# Question about abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

"$ab=0$ implies that $a=0$ or $b=0$", does this mean that we can have $a=b=0$? I dont understand if or means that if $a=0$ then $b \not= 0$?

Comment: I think the "or" in this statement is inclusive; that is, it means (logically) that at least one of $a = 0$, $b = 0$ holds.

Comment: In mathematical speech, we say that $p \text{ or } q$ if either of $p$ and $q$ is true; that is, the only way that $p \text{ or } q$ can be false is if both $p$ and $q$ are false.

Comment: @Mike, they are elements of a commutative ring, but it doesnt matter..im having troubles with the language...what does "or" mean?  Can you see what i mean?

Answer (score 7):

In math, "or" always means inclusive or. In this case, "$a = b = 0$" is valid for "$a = 0$ or $b = 0$".

Answer (score 1):

$ab=0$ $\implies$ either $a=0,b=0 \text{  or } a=b=0$

Comment: This is not true in all rings (= the context here). For example in $\Bbb{Z}_4$ we have the counterexample $a=b=\overline{2}$. The question is about the meaning of "or".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen true but the OP is not concerned in rings, just wanted to give a simple statement.

Comment: Read the OP's last comment under the main question. Commutative rings IS the context.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Edit the answer to your liking, i would like to see the perfect answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
a OR b = x

a b | x 
1 1 | 1
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
0 0 | 0
```

If a is $0$ or b is $0$ or they are both $0$, the statement is true.

$a=0$ then $b \not= 0$  This is and exclusive or then the table would look like this:

```
a XOR b = x

a b | x 
1 1 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
0 0 | 0
```